# CentOS 6: Apache 2.4 drop-in replacement for Apache 2.2 via yum?

Tags: centos6, yum, httpd

I've a CentOS 6.6 installation with the stock Apache 2.2 package. I need to upgrade it to Apache 2.4, but I want a true **drop-in replacement** for the installed package, not [something that goes into /opt to work side-by-side](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138899/centos-install-using-yum-apache-2-4/138903#138903).

Also, I need to install it **via yum (not source, not rpm)** because I need an easy way to update it when new minor versions are released.

Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent command I ran to do a drop-in PHP upgrade:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-php56,remi update php\*
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi-httpd24,remi update httpd\*
```

Note: please let's not waste byte answering "why? CentOS has fix backporting!". That's not the issue here.

Comment: Why aren't you using CentOS 7?

Comment: The problem is that the CentOS 6.6 upgrade to CentOS 7 is not supported (see http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool ) and I've SSH-only access to my server..